# JOGL Hardware Shadow Mapping Transparent Shadow Texture

Tags: opengl, shadows, jogl

I'm using hardware shadow mapping on JOGL based on the demo(HardwareShadowMapping) supplied by the distribution. After generating the shadow texture from lights point of view, I apply it to my scene with no problems.

What I'm looking for is soft shadows instead of pitch black shadows. Is there any way that I can change the alpha values while applying the shadow/depth texture? Btw I'm not an expert on OpenGL especially about custom shaders and I don't want to spend more time on understanding and developing custom shaders instead of the game.

Here's a screenshot of the application in case you come up with another solution to what I'm trying to achieve. The game is actually a hack&slash RTS hybrid.Here's the pseudo code of the gl event listener attached to shadow pbuffer.

> ```
>   gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
>   gl.glPolygonOffset(polygonOffsetFactor, polygonOffsetUnits);
>   gl.glEnable(GL.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
>   //render shadow casting geometry
>   gl.glDisable(GL.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
>   gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, lightViewTextureID);
>   gl.glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, textureSize, textureSize);
>   //I sense here a way of updating alpha values of this texture
> ```
>
> [image: Engine Application Sample]

Comment: Hi, still need help?

Comment: Not particularly after this long but an answer would be good for others looking for help